# How to retain values from previous lines in mapreduce

Tags: mapreduce

I am new to this MapReduce. I want to process a log file that has data in below format

```
EXECUTED: 2016-05-19 07:11:15
.AAAAA
EXECUTED: 2016-05-19 07:11:27

EXECUTED: 2016-05-20 08:11:20
.BBBBB
EXECUTED: 2016-05-20 07:11:27
```

I need to calculate execution time of a command e.g. `.AAAAA / .BBBBB`.

First line shows execution started time and last line shows the time of completion.

I want to write a MapReduce program to calculate `exe` time. How can I preserve time from first line, and use later when second `EXECUTED:` will encounter?

Is there any other way to process it?

Thanks,
Sanjay

Answer (score 1):

When the Map method is run to read the value from first line, store the required value in a static variable.

 When the Map method reads the next line, you can use the static variable to compare the data, perform the necessary calculations and pass it on to Reducer.

Comment: Hi Sumit, I was able to use static variable to compare the data. It worked. thanks for your help.